# Call particular filter for particular Razor Pages Route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages, asp.net-core-routing

I have 2 domains (`.com` and `.ru`) and 2 URLs like `site.com/about-us` and `site.ru/o-nas` which should be **redirected to the same page**. The site uses Razor Pages.

Also, the particular URL should be available in the appropriate domain. For example:

- `site.COM/o-nas` should not work and return `Not Found (404)`
- `site.RU/about-us` should not work and return `Not Found (404)`

  I found that filters work OK, but for both for `site.com/about-us` and `site.ru/o-nas` both filters are called.

How to call only 1 for particular URL, is it possible? Thank you, my current code is below.

```
public static class DomainFilters
{
    public static IPageApplicationModelConvention DomainEng(
        this PageConventionCollection con, string pageName, string route = "")
    {
        return con.AddPageApplicationModelConvention(pageName, model =>
        {
            model.Filters.Add(new EnglishActionFilter(route));
        });
    }
    public static IPageApplicationModelConvention DomainRussian(
        this PageConventionCollection con, string pageName, string route = "")
    {
        return con.AddPageApplicationModelConvention(pageName, model =>
        {
            model.Filters.Add(new RussianActionFilter(route));
        });
    }
}

public class EnglishActionFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString().Contains(".ru"))
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
        }
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context) { }
}

public class RussianActionFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString().Contains(".com"))
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
        }
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context) { }
}
```

And finally `ConfigureServices` method from `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.DomainEng("/AboutUs", "about-us");
            options.Conventions.DomainRussian("/AboutUs", "o-nas");
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider implementation of a custom `FilterFactory`:

```
public class LanguageFilterFactory : Attribute, IFilterFactory
{
    public bool IsReusable => false;

    public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString().Contains(".com"))
        {
            return new EnglishActionFilter();
        }

        return new RussianActionFilter();
    }
}
```

This factory will create either an `English` or `Russian` filter (depending on the domain). That's all about its responsibilities. The rest goes to Filters themselves (you'll need to change a code inside the filters to make them validate the page locator):

```
public class RussianActionFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        // you may want to play with RouteData in order to make this check more elegant   
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Contains("About"))
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
        }
    }
}
```

The filter factory is applied in the same way as other filters:

```
[LanguageFilterFactory]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
```

The `Startup.cs` file update:

```
.AddMvcOptions(options =>
{
   options.Filters.Add<LanguageFilterFactory>();
});
```